# Why does Ruby tell me that :class is defined on Class(Kernel) and not Object?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Take any class in Ruby and ask it where certain methods are defined:

```
Object.method :name
#<Method: Class(Module)#name>
```

Ok, great. So, I can use pry or go to ruby-doc.org and read about the :name method defined on Module.

My question is, what is going on here:

```
Object.method :class
#<Method: Class(Kernel)#class>
```

I don't see where the :class method is defined on the Kernel module. I see it defined on the Object class. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object.

The Kernel instance methods are documented in class Object while the module methods are documented here. These methods are called without a receiver and thus can be called in functional form.

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html

Comment: Ha! I totally read this before I asked the question, but for some reason reading from you made it click. I guess it just confused me that I couldn't find that method on Kernel in the docs.

Comment: Ruby is pretty complex, don't feel to bad, glad I could help.